# CSS Slider - animation timing/transition

Tags: css, css-transitions

First, I'm very new to CSS so I wasn't quite sure what to search for exactly.  I have a pretty simple css slider menu.  It works just fine, but I've been asked to make it delay a couple of seconds before it slides in, after the pointer has left the slider.  I've tinkered around with it a bit, but can't achieve the delay I need.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif" !important;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-kerning: 120;
  z-index: 500;
}

.slideMenu {
  font-weight: 100;
  background: #449bb5;
  width: 140px;
  height: 100%;
  padding-right: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -3px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 3px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  left: -180px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.slideMenuTab {
 background: #449bb5;
 position: absolute;
 width: 40px;
 z-index: 1;
 -webkit-box-shadow: -3px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 box-shadow: 3px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 left: 170px;
 transition: all 0.3s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-align: right;
 padding-right: 10px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 height: 30px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 cursor: pointer;

}

.slideMenu:hover, .slideMenu:focus {
  transform: translate3d(180px, 0, 0);
  animation-timing-function: 1s ease-in;
}

.slideMenu .title {
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(50%);
  transform: translateY(50%);
  transform: rotate(-270deg);
  right: -12.5px;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.slideMenu .nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-weight: 300;
}
.slideMenu .nav li {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.slideMenu .nav li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.slideMenu .nav li a:hover {
  color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideMenu">
   <div class="slideMenuTab"><img src="images/FavoriteStar.png"/></div>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a data-type="ticketdialogbutton" data-class="PickTicket">Create Pick</a></li>
      <hr>
      <li><a data-type="ticketdialogbutton" data-class="ReturnTicket">Create Return</a></li>
      <hr>
      <li><a data-type="ticketdialogbutton" data-class="AdjustmentTicket">Create Adjustment</a></li>
      <hr>
      <li><a data-type="ticketdialogbutton" data-class="CreateMTRTicket">Create MTR</a></li>
      <hr>
      <li><a data-type="ticketdialogbutton" data-class="ReceiveMTRTicket">Receive MTR</a></li>
      <hr>
      <li><a href="https://ecom.schwarz.com" target="_blank" data-type="ticketdialogbutton">Order Signage</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Delaying the slider time would most likely be done with the JavaScript (JQuery?). Are you using a 3rd party slider? If so which one? If not you should share your JS code.

Comment: I'm not using any 3rd party or JS code.  Everything is handled with css.  Here's the Jfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/udbL2gtc/

Comment: There is a way to delay the animation but you need to use keyframes with the animation-delay property. [You can see more here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/animation/).

Comment: I figured it out and it was fairly simple.  Had to think of it in terms of "onmouseover" and "onmouseout" events.  That said, all I did was added "transition: .5s ease-in-out 0s;" to my .slideMenu:hover (onmouseover) and added "transition: .75s ease-in-out 1s;" to .slideMenu (onmouseout).  Worked like a charm!

Comment: Here is the updated Jfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/udbL2gtc/4/